# Change columns every 5 rows in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data and have some records.

I want to change every fifth row of data and update the column `ParentId` to be equal of first row Id of five row group - like this:

```
Id      ParentId    ....
-------------------------------
1        1
2        3
3        10
4        5
5        5
6        5
7        2
8        2
9        2
10       2
11       2
12       7
13       7
```

and result I need in SQL Server should be like this:

```
Id      ParentId    ....
-------------------------------
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        1
6        6
7        6
8        6
9        6
10       6
11       11
12       11
13       11
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code if you want update your table:

```
Update YourTable set ParentId= (Ceiling(Id*1.0/5)-1)*5 + 1
```

and if you want just select rows use this :

```
select Id, (Ceiling(Id*1.0/5)-1)*5 + 1 as ParentId from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable
set ParentId = 5 * (Id / 5) + 1
where Id % 5 != 0

update myTable
set ParentId = 5 * ((Id /5) - 1) + 1
where Id % 5 = 0
```